# Elastic search a way to compare all documents between 2 indices with the same template

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have 2 elastic search Indices, they have the same structure,
and I want to compare 2 indices, if the document in one index has the same id in the other index, i want to check field name "status", and brings all the "id", and status of index1 and status of index2 where the statuses are different, for all the records, even if the number of documents of each index is more then 100000

i tried to use:_transform/_preview
but I got only 200 results and not all

Comment: Try to adjust the value:  `size:10000`. It looks like default limit is 200, that's why you are getting this amount