# Compare 2 indices in elastic to find missing documents

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have 2 indices, `index_a` and `index_b`.

The 2 indices have documents with the *almost* the exact same template. `index_b` has some extra fields which was introduced as part of a new feature, but it also has all the fields already present in `index_a`.

We have noticed that that `index_b` is missing about 2000 documents which are present in `index_a`. We found this out by using the `_count` API.

Now the question is, **is there a way to find out the actual missing documents? Only the missing Ids should also be enough for a start.**

Both the indices have a field called `member_id` which is unique for each document and is the same as the document id, so retrieving only the missing id fields should also be enough.

I cannot compare the index directly to the source database because this data comes from an external API.

I have come across a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280022/elastic-search-a-way-to-compare-all-documents-between-2-indices-with-the-same-te), but I am not looking to compare the actual document values, only a particular field and my documents also have different templates.

I came across another post which had the a code similar to the following (I have modified it according to my need) but I am not sure what it is doing as I am very new to the entire elastic stack so I am not aware of all the APIs yet, and it is also providing incorrect result:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_uid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_indices": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "member_id"
          }
        },
        "values_bucket_filter_by_index_count": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "count_indices"
            },
            "script": "params.count < 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
    "took": 951,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 10,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "group_by_uid": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 10,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 6293147,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "1004451",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "1004456",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "1004462",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "1004464",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "1004568",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "1004569",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "1004570",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "1004612",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "1004613",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "1004614",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "count_indices": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I say this result is incorrect because when I search for these ids, these documents are present in both the indices.